# Porque não tem como marcar uma resposta como favorita?

Tags: suporte

Tem algumas respostas de algumas pessoas que acho ótimas, porém o máximo que consigo fazer, positivamente, é dar um +1(*up*) ou compartilhar nas redes sociais. Eu pensei numa seguinte hipótese, de poder ver todas as respostas (de outras pessoas em outros problemas além dos meus) que possivelmente eu favoritaria.

Porque não tem como marcar uma resposta como favorita?

Comment: Tem tanta diferença assim pra favoritar a pergunta? Já que as duas, pergunta e resposta, existem em conjunto.

Comment: @Gabe sei lá, as vezes a pergunta é ruim mas a resposta é boa.

Comment: pode ser, claro. Mas o favorito não é muito além de um bookmark glorificado. Não tem peso na reputação, não ajuda em rankeamento, é apenas uma maneira de guardar os posts que você considera úteis - sejam por boas perguntas, ou por boas respostas, ou por ambos.

Comment: @Gabe pensei numa medalha: "Resposta com 1000 favoritadas" hehe... mas não foi isso não, foi a questão mesmo de guardar aquela resposta em vez da pergunta. Porque também no SOen tem paginação, e não sei exatamente a ordem que aparece as respostas.

Comment: Olha seria interessante e assim poderia colocar notificações acaso: Editem, ganhe muitos downs ou deletem e novos comentários. Se eu favoritar a pergunta recebo notificações gerais, se "favoritar" a pergunta recebo notificações sobre o ocorrido na pergunta. Sei que ficaria meio Facebook da vida, mas seguir conteudo é interessante para nós, creio eu.

Answer (score 3):

Isso já foi solicitado há tempos e foi recusado.

Os favoritos servem apenas para ter um local para você lembrar de algo que gostou, nesse ponto saber qual é a página é suficiente. Com o tempo eu cheguei à conclusão que é um mecanismo feito para para marcar algo que quer acompanhar de perto quando tem alterações ou voltar logo depois, muitas vezes marcando temporariamente. Pelo que entendi nunca foi intenção ser um mecanismo como é o que temos no navegador, até porque se o navegador já tem um bom, pra quer criar algo para substituí-lo.

Não muda muito favoritar a pergunta e aí olhar as respostas, provavelmente por isso se optou por não fazer. Mas eu acho útil. No SOpt menos porque costuma ter poucas respostas :) Eu entendo sua necessidade, mas acho que é melhor usar a uma ferramenta externa do navegador para guardar o que gostou muito.

Mas acho que a intenção é dar um mecanismo básico para o foco da atividade do site, e não dar uma ferramental completo. Podiam fazer um *premium*, né? Mas a filosofia não é essa.

Se realmente for muito importante recomendo você usar os favoritos do navegador onde você pode por o *link* para a resposta.